# Can liquibase be helpful if the aim is to only automate execution of SQL queries?

Tags: spring-boot, maven, liquibase

My understanding of using Liquibase is as follows:

1. It is a repository for SQL queries migration on to Production database.
2. If xml is prefered ,it has a changelog.xml file which contains changesets which carry instructions in xml tags to perform actions like create, drop alter table etc.

What I want to achieve and for which I am evaluating if liquibase can serve my purpose.

1. My deployment process on UAT/Production have EAR and DB scripts execution as the major aspects.
2. I already have the .sql files which are to be fired in a particular sequence post which the EAR is to be brought up. These .sql files contain DDL as well as DML queries and stored procedures.
3. My aim is to automate the execution of these .sql scripts which is presently carried out manually.

Since liquibase works on an xml to generate the .sql, can my situation where .sqls are already available be proceeded with. Any inputs will be much appreciated.

Comment: I suggest starting with the Liquibase docs to learn more about it (it goes well beyond "repository for SQL Queries migration").

Answer (score 1):

[Liquibase supports multiple formats](https://docs.liquibase.com/concepts/changelogs/changelog-formats.html). XML is only one of them. You can use SQL format. You will have to just add some comments in your scripts with meta information for Liquibase.

You did not provide much information, but what you want to do is exactly what Liquibase is for - upgrade database structure and data when you release a new version of your Java (?) application.

Comment: Yes correct ,I need to use liquibase to automate the process of running a set of sql queries which is presently being done manually. My release process has two components 1. EAR and 2. DB SQL scripts. Before the EAR is brought up, these scripts are to be executed in a particular order. These scripts have joins, stored procedures and not just CRUD operations.